# Have occured error in the following given code in the below website

Tags: android

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Have occurred error in the following given code in the below website

```
   package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import com.facebook.android.*;
 import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

  public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

   Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   <i> setContentView(R.layout.main);  < i>  I have gotten error here

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
      });
   }

  @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
  }
```

`setContentView(R.layout.main);`
The error tells us to create a field `main` in type `layout`. I tried it but `R.java` file cannot be modified manually. 
How can I solve this error?

Comment: What is the error? Could you modify your question title to reflect the error you get. THis will help others find this question and solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to your res directory, resources.

res/layout/main.xml is the file it expects you to create.